# Indulging trigonometric function as substituent in integration

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

Sometimes in order to find integral I was taught to substitute the variable with a suitable trigonometric function. For example if the denominator is in the form $(a^2+x^2)$ we tend to replace $x$ with $\tan\theta$ and then proceed with integration. Again for some cases we replace the variable with $\sin\theta/\cos\theta$. But isn't that wrong to do so? Because the value of variable can be anything, it could be more than $1$ as well as less than $-1$.  So when we are replacing that variable with $\sin\theta$ shouldn't it be wrong  Since value of $\sin\theta$ cannot be more than $1$? Again if $\tan\theta$ is used in some cases we might obtain the integral in the form of an inverse circular function. But while considering the replacement we are limiting the integral(in the form of inverse trig functions) within the principle value. So is this correct too?

Lets say we encountered a problem which requires integral of a certain function. One can find the integral in numerous ways. However the format of the equation is such that if we replace the variable with a trigonometric function, it becomes a lot easier and shorter to find the integral. My question is that if we are to replace the variable with a suitable trigonometric function, there might be for some value of the variable, value of trigonometric function might not exist. So is this a correct way to solve such problems?

I know for most of the cases this way(above) is correct kust being curious *if* there might  be any exception or anything.

Now the second question is that if we solve in that way  and the integral turns out to be a inverse circular function like $a\sin^-1\theta +c$ then aren't we limiting the integral within the bounds of principle values of theta?

**I am asking this question just out of curiousity. I might have missed some crucial things which wouldn't have led me to these questions**

Comment: I think that you should be a bit more specific.

Comment: Tip: Use `\sin \theta` while typing MathJax to get $\sin \theta$.

Comment: If the substitution involves $\tan(u)$, then since the range of $\tan(u)$ is $\left(-\infty, +\infty\right)$, there seems to be no problem.  If instead, you are using $\sin(u)$ against something like $(a^2 - x^2)$, then you can make the substitution $a\sin(u) = x \implies a^2\sin^2(u) = x^2.$  So, in this situation the **range problem** that you are referring to is **remedied** by the scalar in front of the $\sin(u)$, namely the scalar $= a$.

Comment: Ohh I missed out that usually $x$ is replaced with $\sin\theta$ or $\cos\theta$ whenever those functions involve roots for which the whole part within the root cannot be negative.........

Comment: But the issue of values of $\theta$ then?

Comment: "But the issue of values of $\theta$ then?" : I do not understand this question.  Please re-phrase as if you were talking to a 16 year old.

Comment: I meant when we are considering $x=\sin\theta$ there could be innumerous values of $\theta$ for a single value of $x$. When we find integrals using such substitution often we obtain integrals in the form of inverse trigonometric functions. So aren't we limiting the value of integral within the bounds of principal values of $\theta$?

Comment: Yes, we certainly are.  Also, we have to be careful when we specify (for example) $x = \sin(\theta)$ that the range of values that $x$ takes on are a subset of $[-1, 1].$  The normal convention is to presume that $x = \sin(\theta)$ means that $\theta = \text{Arcsin}(x)$, coupled with the convention that $(-\pi/2) \leq \theta \leq (\pi).$  Note that the first expression, $x = \sin(\theta)$ simplifies computing $dx = \cos(\theta)d\theta.$  Thus $(1/2) = \int_0^1 xdx$ which can be alternatively computed as $\int_0^{(\pi/2)} \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)d\theta.$   ...see next comment.

Comment: Using that $(1/2) \times \sin(2\theta) = \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$, we have that  $\int_0^{(\pi/2)} \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)d\theta = (1/2) \times \int_0^{(\pi/2)} \sin(2\theta)d\theta.$  This equals $$\frac{1}{2} \left[-\frac{1}{2} \times \cos(2\theta)\right]_{0}^{(\pi/2)} = -\frac{1}{4} \times \left[(-1) - (1)\right] = \frac{1}{2}.$$